# How can I use data within an array that is located in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Essentially I have a script I am putting together that will run a trace against all of our Exchange servers, this is intended for agents using remote Powershell as piping is not supported in the scenario.

With this I am storing the results in an array before exporting to a CSV, the issue I have is that the recipients are in themselves an array.

So my question is how do I reference the array within the array in order to put the recipients into the exported CSV. With my current script the below columns are written:

Server  Timestamp   EventId Source  Sender  Recipients  MessageSubject

The recipients column is then populated with:

@{Recipients=System.Collections.ArrayList}

```bsh
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [String]$Start,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [String]$End,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [String]$Sender,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [String]$Recipient,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [String]$Subject
)

$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri <HostAddress> -Authentication basic -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

$ifBlock = "0"
$tracingResults = @()

#Get-ExchangeServer | Select Name
#ForEach ($S in (Get-ExchangeServer | select -ExpandProperty name))
if (($Recipient -eq "" -And $Subject -eq "") -And ($ifBlock -eq "0" -or $ifBlock -eq "R+S"))
        {
        $ifBlock = "R+S"
        ForEach ($S in (Get-ExchangeServer | select -ExpandProperty name)){
        $Tracing = Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -server $S -Start $Start -End $End -Sender $Sender | select Timestamp,ServerHostname,EventId,Source,Sender,Recipients,MessageSubject
         if ($tracing -eq ""){
            Write-Output ($S + " : No emails found here")
            }
         if ($Tracing -ne ""){
            $TracingObject = Get-Variable Tracing
                try{
                    $tracingResults += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    Server = $S
                    Timestamp = $TracingObject.Value[0] | select Timestamp
                    EventId = $TracingObject.Value[0] | select EventId
                    Source = $TracingObject.Value[0] | select Source
                    Sender = $TracingObject.Value[0] | select Sender
                    Recipients = $TracingObject.Value[0] | select Recipients
                    MessageSubject = $TracingObject.Value[0] | select MessageSubject
                    } | Select-Object Server,Timestamp,EventId,Source,Sender,Recipients,MessageSubject
                }
                catch{}
                #Write-Output ($tracing)
            }
        }
        }

Remove-PSSession $Session
$tracingResults | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ./trace.csv
```

Comment: can you join the recipients into a string? that is the usual way to stuff a set of values into one column. something like `$Recipients -join ';'` looks like it would work.

Comment: You don't have a nested array (arrays in array) but hashtables in an array (+ alot of the code can be skipped to make the problem more precies and on point)

Comment: Forgive me my overall knowledge of Powershell scripting is limited, In this scenario I have an array with hash tables (Originally thought to be an array within an array) however the recipients data is in fact an array as this is how it is returned. 

Any suggestion on how I would convert the array to a usable string, using [string] and out-string result in nothing being written to the CSV for the recipients column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this solution did not work for me either T-Me, I have however used this approach for other scripts.

For reference I resolved this by looping over each result returned rather than trying to deal with all of the returned results per server in one go:

```
ForEach ($S in (Get-ExchangeServer | select -ExpandProperty name)){
        $Tracing = Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -server $S -Start $Start -End $End -Sender $Sender | select Timestamp,EventId,Source,Sender,Recipients,MessageSubject,MessageId,OriginalClientIp
        [string]$TracingString = $Tracing
            ForEach ($log in $Tracing){

             $tracingResults += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                            Server = $S
                            Timestamp = $log.TimeStamp
                            EventId = $log.EventId
                            Source = $log.Source
                            Sender = $log.Sender
                            Recipients = $log.Recipients
                            MessageSubject = $log.MessageSubject
                            OriginalClientIp = $log.OriginalClientIp
                            MessageId = $log.MessageId
                            } | Select-Object Server,Timestamp,EventId,Source,Sender,Recipients,MessageSubject,MessageId,OriginalClientIp
                }
            }
        }

$tracingresults | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ./trace.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you created the `$tracingResults` way to complicated... However the way you did it, you need a `PSCustomObject` not a `PSObject`. Here is a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
 $tracingResults = @()
 1..3 | foreach {
     $tracingResults += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                        Server = "serv$_"
                        Timestamp = "time$_"
                        EventId = "EventId$_"
                        Source = "Source$_"
                        Sender = "Sender$_"
                        Recipients = "Recipients$_"
                        MessageSubject = "MessageSubject$_"
                        } | Select-Object Server,Timestamp,EventId,Source,Sender,Recipients,MessageSubject
}
$tracingresults | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation
```